# Drupal 7: Using Rules on embedded webform block

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform, drupal-rules

I have a "Subscribe to our Newsletter" webform (can be any webform) - say node/41 - that I embedded in a block (block id is "client-block-14"). This is done so that it can be displayed in different regions on different pages. There are no direct links to node/41.

When submitting the form I do not want the user to be redirected. I want the user to stay on the page he/she is currently on (e.g Home, Products, etc...) and displaying a custom message stating that the submission was successful.

The catch is that I only want a rule for this webform and not for other webforms (contact us) on the site.

Here is my rule that I tried.

1. After new content is saved
2. Condition 1: content type is webform
3. AND condition 2: node id is 41
4. Action: Display message

How do I convert this rule (and adding no-redirect) to work on the embedded block as it clearly does not have a node id but a block id?

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting to the current page as the destination as an action.

Comment: how would I do that? What action can I choose in rules that does this?